# How to update output file after executing each cell in notebook with nbconvert

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, nbconvert

I'm using following command to execute "file1.ipynb" and write the output to "file2.ipynb".

```
jupyter nbconvert file1.ipynb --to notebook --execute --output file2.ipynb
```

It appears "file2.ipynb" is created only after the whole notebook is executed. However I want to see the output for already executed cells halfway through the execution (as opposed to seeing it at the very end).

Is there a way to update the output file after executing each cell?

Comment: I don't think there is a way no, nbconvert execution API runs the whole notebook at once. If you want partial execution you will have to use the regular notebook instead.